# Aren't there two ways of putting a sentence with an i-adjective into past tense? かった and でした?

Tags: conjugations, past

今日ヨガは最も難しいことです。

> 1. 今日ヨガは最も難しかったことです。
> 2. 今日ヨガは最も難しいことでした。

Are both sentences correct? What are the different implications?
I haven't worked with 最も yet, I would try to use 一番 here instead. What I perceive as my problem is かった or でした. Please, point out all the things.

今日一番難しいことはヨガです。

> 1. 今日一番難しかったことはヨガです。
> 2. 今日一番難しいことはヨガでした。

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to end these sentences with ことです and ことでした?

Comment: In English, "The most difficult thing today was Yoga" feels more natural than "Today, Yoga was most difficult". That is the reason. I can't judge if it is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most natural ways to phrase your sentence are as follows:

> 今日はヨガが一番難しかった（です）。
> ( Out of all the activities I did today, ) Yoga was the most difficult.
> *Note: emphasis is on the word "yoga". です can be added but is not necessary.*
>
> 今日一番難しかったのはヨガでした。
> Today the most difficult part was Yoga.
> *Note: の can be replaced with こと, they are interchangeable.*
>
> 今日のヨガが一番難しかった（です）。
> ( Out of all the yoga I've done, ) Today's yoga was the most difficult.
> *Note: emphasis is on the word "today".*

In general, 一番 and 最も are interchangeable, however 一番 indicates an explicit number one ranking, whereas 最も does not necessarily indicate a number one ranking when referring to a group, just like the word "most".

> 彼はクラスで一番頭のいい生徒の一人です。✘
> 彼はクラスで最も頭のいい生徒の一人です。✔
> He is one of the most intelligent students in his class.

Comment: You cleared up much for me. The second sentence you wrote 0.今日一番難しかったのはヨガでした。Could become 1. 今日一番難しのはヨガでした。as well as 2. 今日一番難しかったのはヨガです。1.Today the most difficult part was Yoga (implying Yoga is always difficult.) and 2. The part that was most difficult today is Yoga. (In English it feels as if one should not mix tenses here.) In Japanese, sentences with i-adjectives should be transformed into past tense by かった never です. In this case there are somewhat two sentences though. Is 2. as awkward in Japanese? Does 1. imply what I think it does?

Comment: @NearE.Fox This link might be useful: https://ncode.syosetu.com/n2205dy/2/
According to this article, tenses are not as strict in Japanese and in fact, there is no strictly defined "present tense". In my experience, however, if an adjective is placed at the end of a sentence, it should be converted into past tense. If it is in the middle of a sentence as part of some clause, it may be okay to just leave it in its base form.